# jquery hightlight any div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an effect that could highlight a div on page(and blur body)...

my html code...

```
<div class="highlighter">content goes here</div>
```

jquery code...

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('body').css("background-color","black").fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function() {
           $('.highlighter').fadeTo('slow', 0.9);
       });

   }, 5000);
});
```

but my jquery code is not working as expected, what i am trying to do is:  Load the page, blur the page(body) with lower opacity or black background but without .highlighter div so this div should be highlighted for 5 seconds then blur effect removes from website and website would be worked as normal, please help me to achieve the effect, thanks for help.

Comment: I don't see you referencing the `div` with class `highlighter` in your code. And what is `horzad`?

Comment: The HTML you show us has nothing to do with the javascript you show us.  Please fill in the missing HTML or the missing javascript so we can see both.

Comment: @kei sorry, that was typo, i edited question

Comment: @jfriend00 i edited question, please check

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem about the unwanted opacity change for children elements? Because when you change the opacity of the body, the div's opacity will change too.

To avoid that, you can create another div, position it absolutely to cover the entire page and set its opacity to, say, 0.2, and assign its z-index to a value (say, 1000). Then assign z-index of the div you want to highlight to a value bigger than that (1001).